# Не работает код для отправки данных в телеграм бота. JS

Tags: javascript

```
var chatid = "id (вырезан)";
var token = "токен (вырезан)";
var name = document.getElementById('user-name');
var contact = document.getElementById('user-contact');
var message = document.getElementById('message');
var text = "text";
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
btn.onclick {
  var z=$.ajax({  
  type: "POST",  
  url: "https://api.telegram.org/bot"+token+"/sendMessage?chat_id="+chatid,
  data: "&parse_mode=HTML&text="+encodeURIComponent(text), 
  }); 
 };
```

Comment: на каком домене вы запускаете этот скрипт? Какие политики CORS установлены на сервере? Что передаётся в заголовках?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно заменить `btn.onclick { ... }` на `btn.onclick = function(){ ... }` и тогда получится так:

```js
const chatid = '1463152388';
const token = '2036441771:AAHff9GfBVo6QSQeBci7qV2lPFBImamcYpA';
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const pre = document.getElementById('console');
btn.onclick = function (){
  const text = 'text';
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: `https://api.telegram.org/bot${token}/sendMessage?chat_id=${chatid}`,
    data: 'parse_mode=HTML&text=' + encodeURIComponent(text),
  })
  .done((data) => pre.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2))
  .fail((err) => console.error('error', err));
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">Отправить тестовое сообщение</button>
<pre id="console"></pre>
```